# Collapsing a table into a row of markers

Tags: css, responsive-design

The main question here is **how to make a table render as a set of inline cells**? What follows is some background to the question:

I'm coding a calendar on my responsive site. The calendar is a `<table>`, where each cell represents a day and each day contains a `<table>` which has two columns, one listing times and the other events:

[image: Base calendar]

But since the site is responsive, I want to make the css of the calendar look  on mobile devices something like this:

[image: CSS Small]

(The idea being that when the user taps on one of the dates, they will see a small list of events for that day; this is very similar to how the Apple Calendar on the iPhone works).

This question is about the inner tables, not the outer table. The goal is to transfer a table that looks like this:

```
10:30 | Event 1
12:45 | Event 2
18:30 | Event 3
```

Into something that looks like this:

```
• • •
```

Now I want to do this in CSS (which will be nested in a media query). However the result I am getting, looks like this:

[image: CSS current]

This is the relevant piece of CSS I'm using:

```
.calendar table, .calendar table>tbody>tr, .calendar table>tbody {
    display: inline;
}
.calendar table>tbody>tr td:first-child {
    display: none;
}
.calendar table>tbody>tr td:last-child {
    display: inline-block;
}
.calendar>tbody>tr>td {
    height: 20px;
    max-width: 35px;
    width: 14.2857142857143%;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.calendar table a {
    display: none;
}
.calendar table tr>td:last-child:before {
    content: "•";
    visibility: visible;
    margin: 0;
}
```

I've created a fiddle illustrating the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/hvE8j/

Comment: Does this help? http://jsfiddle.net/qolami/hvE8j/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hvE8j/5/

Try floating the `td:last-child`:

```
.calendar table tr>td:last-child {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, somehow I thought that since everything is `inline`, that shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: why did you select this as best answer? its fiddle is not even working.

Answer (score 1):

you should use float right to sort them horizontal.

[**See fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/hvE8j/4/)

```
.calendar table>tbody>tr, .calendar table>tbody
{
    display: inline;
    max-height: 10px;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Jakub, my fiddle is working, meanwhile his fiddle is not. I don't know why you picked the other as best answer. :(

Comment: They both work equally well for me, I flipped a coin, checked the winner and upvoted the loser.

Answer (score 1):

Change display of `.calendar table>tbody>tr, .calendar table>tbody` to `inline-block`

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hvE8j/6/)